# How can I add an extra configuration file for mysql (my.cnf)

Tags: mysql, unix

I want to add and extra configuration file for MySQL on UNIX, let's call it my2.cnf. So when MySQL starts, it would read the options of that file too.

[Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/option-files.html) it says that I can put a file  on the following places:

- /etc/my.cnf
- SYSCONFDIR/my.cnf
- $MYSQL_HOME/my.cnf
- defaults-extra-file   The file specified with --defaults-extra-file=path, if any
- ~/.my.cnf User-specific options

I would like something like this "default-extra-file", but avoiding to enter this command on the mysql prompt.

Is there an option in the cnf file like:

```
 extra-conf-file=/path/to/my/file/my2.cnf
```

(Unfortunately that does not work)

Is that even possible? Can I use the default my.cnf file to add another configuration file that will be read when I start themysql service?

(Using $MYSQL_HOME/my.cnf is good enough for me, but I would like to know if I can explicetely tell so it can be read or ignored according to the main my.cnf global file).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I guess this is what you want right ?

```
!include /path/to/my/file/my2.cnf
```

You can also include a complete set of files from a directory using:

```
!includedir /path/to/my.cnf.d
```

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I wanted! Works like charm. And thanks for the tip about includedir.

Comment: Nowhere found any answer on related question: can we use file name patterns by regexp or some asterisks? Anyone knows can we `!include /path/to/my/file/*.cnf` or `!includedir /path/to/my.cnf.d/*.cnf` ? So there  `/path/to/my.cnf.d/file.cnf` WILL be included but  `/path/to/my.cnf.d/another.notcnf` will NOT. Is here such an option?

Comment: try it and see; here's the documentation https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/option-files.html#option-file-inclusions