# MySQL 5.5.38 not picking option file from /usr/etc/my.cnf

Tags: mysql

I am using mysql version 5.5.38 on Centos 6.4

```
$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.38, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1
```

in the help it says

```
Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf /usr/etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf
```

I dont have either `/etc/my.cnf` or `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` on my machine.

I created `/usr/etc/my.cnf` with following content

```
[mysqld]
default-storage-engine = InnoDB
```

I restarted mysql server. When I create a new table, it still uses the **MyISAM** as storage engine instead of **InnoDB**

If I use the `/etc/my.cnf` for my config file, it uses InnoDB as storage engine.

My question is why my settings are not working when using `/usr/etc/my.cnf` file ?

Can I also use two files as configuration files ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an alternative way to do this using [How can I add an extra configuration file for mysql (my.cnf)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15695937/how-can-i-add-an-extra-configuration-file-for-mysql-my-cnf?rq=1)

I included `!include /usr/etc/my.cnf` in my /etc/my,cnf file and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Mysql uses one config file. How to find its location read [here](http://www.dbasquare.com/2012/04/01/how-to-find-mysql-configuration-file/)